# Getting params passed in service get URL on backend side

Tags: javascript, angular, express

It is the first time I try to use the URL filtering feature, and I'm not sure about what I did. I have this service:

```
getFiltered(filterData: any[]): Observable<BreedingSheet[]> {
console.log('from service', filterData);
return this.http.get<BreedingSheet[]>(${this.breedingSheetsUrl}/filter/search?family=test)
.pipe(
  map(filteredResult => filteredResult['breedingSheets']),
  shareReplay()
 );
}
```

And this on backend:

```
router.get('/filter/search', async(req, res, next) => {
console.log('call backend from service');

console.log('family is', req.params.family);

await BreedingSheet.find()
.populate('creator')
.then(documents => {
 res.status(200).json({
  message: 'filtered breeding sheets succesfully loaded',
  breedingSheets: documents
    });
  });
});
```

But when the call occurs, the backend console logs me: *family is undefined*

Did I miss something?

Comment: try with this  `req.query.family` instead of `req.params.family`

Comment: What you've shown for the client isn't actually valid syntax. You should be able to narrow this down to either: 1. client is making wrong request; or 2. server is responding incorrectly to the right one. Use an alternative client (Postman, curl, ...) or check the Network tab. I'd suggest also reading https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was:

```
req.query
```